# ошибка TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть код, его смысл таков: Пользователь вводит переменные (query, where) для поиска по локальной базе данных, код ищет ResID в базе с помощью переданных переменных, и выводит пользователю полученную информацию, Так получается, что в базе при поиске могут выпасть не один ResID, и пользователю даётся краткая информация о записи в базе данных, и просит выбрать нужную, и в то время как если при вводе переменных выдаётся 1 ResID, всё проходит идеально, и запись показывается, но если выпадает больше 1 записи, Python признает в функции (func4) "NoneType" object, и выпадает исключение, в чём проблема так и не понял, экспериментальным путём узнал что func4 и в случае если 1 ResID, и если больше одного является - NoneType, но в 1-ом случае он успешно выполняется, а во 2-ом уже нет

Вероятная часть кода с ошибкой:

```
def func0(message):
    global where
    global resID
    sumresid = func1(query, where)  # Возвращает ВСЕ найденные resID
    if len(sumresid) > 1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Info:')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Results: ' + str(len(sumssid)))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, IPMO(message, sumresid))  # если найдено больше 1 resID, передаёт список функции IPMO которая показывает все найденные записи, и даёт выбрать нужную пользователю.
    else:
        resID = func2(query, where)  # Если найден был только 1 resID, возвращает resID
        compRes(message)

def IPMO(message, listOfresID):
    sumresid = listOfresID
    num = 0
    while True:
        print('DEBUG: sumResID: ' + str(sumresid))
        if str(sumresid) == '[]':
            print('DEBUG: IF construct (str(sumresid) == "[]") is Called!')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choice profile (enter resID):')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, IPMO_Choice)
            break
        print('DEBUG: While is Working!')
        readyResID = sumresid[0]  # Берёт 1 ResID из списка
        resultuple = func3(readyResID)  # Возвращает tuple с данными по ResID
        resid = resultuple[0]
        var1 = resultuple[1]
        var2 = resultuple[2]
        var3 = resultuple[3]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '[ ! ]: Result #' + str(num))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ResID: ' + ssid)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Var1: ' + var1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Var2: ' + var2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Var3: ' + var3)
        num = num + 1
        sumresid.remove(sumresid[0])

def IPMO_Choice(message):
    print('DEBUG: Called local func: IPMO_Choice')
    global ResID
    ResID = message.text
    debugCheckResID()
    compRes(message)

def debugCheckResID():
    # Придумана чисто для теста
    print('DEBUG: Called local func: debugCheckResID')
    print('DEBUG: Selected ResID: ' + ResID)

def compRes(message):
    print('DEBUG: Called local func: compRes')
    print('DEBUG: Type of func Func5: ' + str(type(mainInfoResult())))  # Результат: DEBUG: Type of func Func4: <class 'NoneType'>
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ResID found! (' + ResID + ')')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Compiling result...')
    Func4()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Func4...COMPILED!')
```

Вот какой Traceback возвращается:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 1587, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=60)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 413, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 108, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```